# Web Service in asp.net

Tags: web-services, soap

Hi I am new to webservice  in .net.
My questions is do we really require to have the SSL for accessing web methods visible to me.

and if require, where it should be on my side or on cliet side who is providing me webmethods?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

SSL is not required.

Also, you should be using WCF for all new development.

Answer (score 0):

SSL is not required. I use ASHX to create a generic handler. I find that it is a lot more flexible because you can pass in querystring quite easily